# What will be the heapdump size if I set the Max Heap size = 2 Gb?

Tags: java, out-of-memory, websphere, heap-memory

I have set my max heap size to 2 GB  on my Websphere server console. I want to know what will be size of my heapdump files created during Out of Memory errors. Will they be greater than 2GB or equal to 2GB or less than 2GB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the type of the dump. Accordingly with the article provided by IBM:

1) PHD dump takes about 20 percent of Java heap size

2) HPROF dump takes about the same as Java heap size

3) IBM system dumps - about Java heap size + 30 percent

Source: https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-memoryanalyzer/

Normally you will get PHD with Javacore on OutOfMemoryError, so you can expect it to be about 20% of heap. But you have to keep in mind that OutOfMemoryError could be thrown several times within rather short timeframe, so several dumps could be created.